# Kali Linux Installation Not Dectecting Unallocated Space

Tags: kali-linux

[image]

I'm trying to install kali linux but failed. 
I follow the steps that described [Here.](http://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows) But it's not showing me `Guided - use the largest continuous free space` and after checking the partition. Kali LInux shows unusable space to Unallocated space.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because your partition table is "full".

Judging by the fact that there is no EFI System Partition on the disk, your Windows installation is a BIOS one, which means the disk is an MBR disk instead of a GPT disk. And you already got four (which is the [maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Disk_partitioning)) primary partitions on it, so you cannot create another one even when there is unallocated space.

You'll need to by some means convert `University Data` and `Software` to logical partitions (which will be contained by an extended partition), then you can create ONE partition with the unallocated space; or you can convert the disk to a GPT disk, which requires you to convert your Windows installation to a UEFI one (and your motherboard needs to have UEFI instead of BIOS for booting that).